# input validation not working on asp.net mvc 4 model sent as JSON

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a model and a form in the view. I have a simple field of string which is called description. I'm able to insert scripts like: `<script>alert('xss')</script>` to that field.
I can see that in other actions on my site with other models I can't
I do not have an `AllowHtml` or anything like that.

the only difference is that for this model I use a post with a json object and content-type of application/json
the `ModelState.IsValid` is returning true. even though there is a description property with an xss script on it...

and for the other actions I make a simple ajax post.

why isn't the validation input work on this kind of JSON ajax posts?
how can I prevent xss across the entire site for this kind of ajax requests?

thanks

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same thing with no solution yet.  Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: tried [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846577/xss-validation-from-mvc-action-from-json-ajax-post/45851726)

Comment: I know the differences and solution. Just provide technical details in your question. such as Model, Binding Model (ViewModel) if exists. form method for each view and finally `requestValidationMode` version inside your *web.config* file. If not, It's not clear to answer for any body.

Answer (score 0):

It is because ValidateInput is only for FormValueProvider. As for JsonValueProvider, you need to roll out your own mechanism.

Steps 
1) Create a marker attribute `CustomAntiXssAttribute` 
2) Create a custom model binder by sub-classing `DefaultModelBinder`
3) Overrides `BindProperty` method -> get the attempted value for the underlying property, sanitize it and assign it to the view model property.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441482/antixss-protection-html-model-properties) out.

Edited:
Replace the line `var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyDescriptor.Name);` with `var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue((string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bindingContext.ModelName) ? string.Empty : bindingContext.ModelName + ".") + propertyDescriptor.Name);` in order to support nested ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

try using AntiXssLibrary from Nuget, and by using getSafeHtmlContent. you can get the safe content while you're saving your records to db.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a Sanitizer library like [this one](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer), you can choose which HTML tags you want to be filtered out.